# OpenVino on MacOS using Anaconda

Tags: macos, conda, openvino

How do you go about installing OpenVino using Anaconda. Will this be possible with prerequisites like OpenCV and CMake that are required for installation.

```
(IntelEnv) ChrNinja@ChrNinja demo % ./demo_squeezenet_download_convert_run.sh
target_precision = FP16
[setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized


###################################################



Downloading the Caffe model and the prototxt
Installing dependencies
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Processing /Users/christianh/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/a7/c1/ea/cf5bd31012e735dc1dfea3131a2d5eae7978b251083d6247bd/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/70/1935c770cb3be6e3a8b78ced23d7e0f3b187f5cbfab4749523ed65d7c9b1/requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/e3/afebe61c546d18fb1709a61bee788254b40e736cff7271c7de5de2dc4128/idna-2.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/2b/26e37a4b034800c960a00c4e1b3d9ca5d7014e983e6e729e33ea2f36426c/certifi-2020.4.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/e5/df302e8017440f111c11cc41a6b432838672f5a70aa29227bf58149dc72f/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, idna, chardet, certifi, urllib3, requests
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyYAML-5.3.1.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Error on or near line 150; exiting with status 1
```

Comment: Is there an actual issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I have looked up PATH issues and changed that, watched a video on MacOS anaconda install in which the person uses a virtual env and many more research. CMake works now but during prerequistes install it searches for pyyaml in the systems Python 2.7. I am using my command in the Anaconda virtual env but it still referring back to the system’s Python

Comment: _I am using my command in the Anaconda virtual env but it still referring back to the system’s Python_ Can you share the terminal commands and output showing that?

Comment: @AMC I have updated my question. Is it ok that the shell script reverts back to Python2.7? In the script it checks whether Python 3.X is installed (which it is in Anaconda) however it still uses the Systems Python.

Comment: _I have updated my question. Is it ok that the shell script reverts back to Python2.7? In the script it checks whether Python 3.X is installed (which it is in Anaconda) however it still uses the Systems Python._ I beg your pardon, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: I have successfully installed OpenVino. What I meant before is this: OpenVino's script checks the system to see whether some form of Python3.X is installed. This line of code does not output an error because I have Python3.7 installed. The error output shows that it is using Python2.7 to check for libraries. Here was my fix: 'which pip' output Anaconda's pip; however, 'which pip3' output System Libraries pip which I did not want to use. So I modified the script which was using pip3 to only pip. Now it was using Anaconda's pip and the demo script ran successfully!

Answer (score 2):

## 1. Update conda to latest version:

conda update --all

## 2. Install the Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ Toolkit:

conda install openvino-ie4py -c openvino

## 3. Install OpenCV. This is required to run a sample:

conda install opencv

## 4. Verify the package installed:

python -c “import openvino”